# Error: package 'lsei' is not installed for 'arch=x64'

Tags: r

I have recently upgraded from R 2.9 (I think) to R 2.13 on my Windows 7 machine. Since the upgrade, I've been having problem loading the following package (lsei.zip).

http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yongwang/

```
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
package 'lsei' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> library(lsei)
Error: package 'lsei' is not installed for 'arch=i386'
```

I have read some thread on Stackoverlow and other R-help forums but their answer doesn't seem to resolve my problem. (e.g. removing an older copy or re-install all the packages)

Nevertheless, I have been able to install and load the package successfully on my Mac machine. So I think it should be something associated with Windows but not sure what it is.

Much appreciated if someone can point me to the right direction and help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
MK

Comment: I have went on to test and found that the package works for R version =< 2.11. However, I have installed Rtools and followed the steps outlined by Duncan Murdoch and Brian Ripley so not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: This is really a question for the package author. It's not on CRAN or any of the other typical repositories. Furthermore, you are not offering enough detail for anybody to offer specific advice..

Comment: Did you try to install it with the command install.packages("lsei")? You may get a bit more details about the error.

Comment: I get the same error message with `dplyr`. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `lsei` Windows binary is probably that it was built using an old version of R and is no longer compatible with more recent versions of R.  When having similar problems in the future, if the source code is available (which it is in this case, at the link you provided), you can just build the binary from source yourself.  See: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages .  To build a binary on Windows, you'll need [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) .

It's a good exercise to go ahead and learn how to build binaries from source.  From your comments above, it seems you tried that but are still having problems.  For convenience, a Windows binary of the `lsei` package built under R 2.15.0 is available here: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/jthetzel-public/lsei_1.0-2.zip .  It works for me on both i386 and x64 R 2.15.0 for Windows.